# Why is the generic for the CrudRepository interface not picking up my imports?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

Adding the model and id class types to the generics diamond for the CrudRepository interface won't recognize what class I'm referring to, in a very weird way I haven't really seen before. Has anyone encountered this? I'll include the POJO model and a gif of the problem hoping it will clarify things.

```
package guru.springframework.spring5webapp.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String firstName, String lastName, Set<Book> books) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.books = books;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public Author setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Author setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public Author setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
        return this;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Author{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", firstName='").append(firstName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", lastName='").append(lastName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", books=").append(books);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Author)) return false;

        Author author = (Author) o;

        return getId() != null ? getId().equals(author.getId()) : author.getId() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN9LR.gif

Basically I'm trying to use IntelliJ to import the statement automatically but it's completely failing at doing so. Also adding the import manually doesn't pick up where to actually look for it.

When I import with the Option + Enter shortcut it does this. "Cannot resolve symbol Author":

```
package guru.springframework.spring5webapp.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<guru.springframework.spring5webapp.model.Author, Long> {
}
```

Author is public so it should be fine right?

Comment: Try invalidate cache & restart in Intellij

Comment: Thanks, that worked! So weird. Damn bug cost me half a day.

Comment: I've put the comment in answers for the benefit of others. Please accept :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invalidate cache & restart in Intellij